# Pandas complaining about key error, even when key exists

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGwW4.png)

I want to count the instances of specific 'Event' in each 'Run'. I have the following Pandas code

```
all_run_counts=all_data_df.sort_values('Event',ascending=False).groupby('Run')
    result=all_run_counts["Event"].value_counts()
```

It gives me a data frame that counts each 'Event' in each 'Run', so far so good.

How I want to just filter specific event type and count instances of that event in each run, but when i do filter with following script, it doesnt work and gives me 'Event' key error when clearly 'Event' is already there as a column:

```
    result.loc[result['Event'] == 'J']
```

What is the reason for this?

I was expecting each Run filtered by specific event so I can compare corresponding value_counts of same event type with various runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By applying `groupby` and `value_counts`, your `result` ends up being a Series, not a dataframe, and thus `Event` is not a column but a MultiIndex level.

You need to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
result = all_run_counts["Event"].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Note that the `groupby` is not really needed here, you can directly use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
result = all_data_df.value_counts().reset_index()
```

Comment: Your first option solves the issue. The second one does not give me value count of the event column, rather it reprints all the columns as is so I believe we do need specify across which column we want value_count.

Comment: also when I do  `result.groupby('Event')` after `result = all_run_counts["Event"].value_counts().reset_index()` to tally the count of each event for each run but having same events grouped together, I get `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f3729f7bb50>`

Comment: That's expected, `groupby` produces a `DataFrameGroupBy`, you have to call a method after this step.